# Display a result in VB

Tags: vb.net

My question is simple yet difficult to find an answer for.  I declared a variable which is the sum of two other variables.  I simply want to display that result on the screen.  I think a msgbox is what I need to use but I'm not sure.

Comment: you didn't state whether or not this is a Web Forms app or a Win Forms app.  can you tell us if this is desktop or web?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
MsgBox("The sum of these numbers is: " & total)
```

Comment: okay, if I wanted to say: "The sum of these numbers is: (total)", how would I go about that?

Comment: `MsgBox("The sum of these numbers is: " & total)`

Comment: there it is, I keep forgetting VB uses & to concatenate instead of +.  Thank you both.

Comment: MsgBox("The sum of these numbers is: " & total)

Comment: Assuming total is an integer or some other numerical type and you're using .NET, you can gain type safety by using Msgbox(total.tostring).  If you're using VB6, Str(Total) will give you your type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Well are you using a website or winforms?

If you're using a website, just create a label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
```

Then in your code behind, just set the message.

```
Dim Variable as Int
lblMessage.Text = Variable.ToString();
```

The same can be used above on a WinForm, but in a Winform you can also use:

```
MessageBox.Show(....);
```

Comment: fyi.. he didn't state that he's using .NET - thought I do the same thing and default to .NET when I'm answering these things.